# (How) Can I prove this sum of simple rational functions does not have more than one maximum?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I want to find out whether functions

$$f(x) = \sqrt{\prod^J_{j=1} {a_j x + b_j}} \cdot x^{c_1+1} \cdot \exp(- c_2 x);\; a_j, b_j, c_1, c_2 >0;\; x \geq 0$$ 
are at most unimodal for positive $x$. I also know that all the $a_j, b_j$ are distinct.

Taking the derivative of the log of the function, I get the expression

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x)) = 0.5 \sum^J_{j=1} \frac{a_j}{a_j x + b_j} + \frac{c_1+1}{x} - c_2  = 0$$

for the locations of the extreme points. How can I argue that there is at most  one solution to this for positive $x$?

Some more background on why I'm doing this:

$f(x)$ is (proportional to) the probability density function of a random variable $x$ I'm trying to sample in an MCMC algorithm. The method I use to sample from that distribution (slice sampling) sometimes breaks if the associated density has more than one maximum, so a reviewer has asked for a proof of unimodality for that density. The online equation solvers I've tried don't work for $J>1$. In my problem, $J$ is on the order of 10 to 40. Plotting the function for various realistic $J, a_j, b_j, c_1, c_2 >0$, it seems very well behaved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the constants are positive, every term in the logarithmic derivative is a strictly decreasing function (except for the constant term), so the logarithmic derivative is strictly decreasing,

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \log f(x) = -\frac12 \sum_{j=1}^J \frac{a_j^2}{(a_jx+b_j)^2} - \frac{c_1+1}{x^2} < 0.$$

Thus the logarithmic derivative can have at most one zero in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds obvious, now that you put it that way ;). Gratefully accepted.